# Flex intellisense forgets flash.*

Tags: apache-flex, intellisense

I am using Eclipse 3.3.2 with the Flex Builder Plugin (3.0.194161) and the Flex SDK 3.2. Recently the intellisense has started forgetting about everything in the flash.* package EXCEPT flash.errors.*

The code still compiles, but attempting to automatically resolve something (CTRL+SPACE) removes any of the flash.* import statements and thus causes a compile error. As it stands I have to either not use CTRL+SPACE, or re-add my flash.* before compiling.

I have tried recreating the workspace/project and have re-installed the Flex SDK, but I still get the same problem.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around the problem by adding the following SWC to my library path: FLEX_SDK\libs\player\10\playerglobal.swc

It looks like the problem is caused by {targetPlayerMajorVersion} no longer resolving, though I have no idea how that happened.

**Edit:** Known bug, as described in [FB-16703](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-16703) and ["Targeting Flash Player 10"](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Targeting+Flash+Player+10)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to [Flex Builder 3.0.2](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/sdk32_fb302.html). I've noticed that older versions of Flex Builder don't like Flash Player 10's new playerglobal.swc.

Comment: I'm actually using Eclipse with the Flex Builder plugin, but I'll upgrade both and see how that goes.